# wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly Issue when active plugins of WordPress Admin Bar Improved

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, css

I am getting the error with the following message when i active my plugins "WordPress Admin Bar Improved":

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexisim\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4094

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexisim\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4094

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexisim\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4094

Following is the related code i found from my plugins which include wp_enqueue_scripts:

```
public function admin_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('wpabi_admin_js', plugins_url('wpabi-admin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0');

}

public function admin_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('wpabi_admin_css', plugins_url('wpabi-admin.css', __FILE__), '', '2.0', 'all');
}
```

What i can do to resolve this kind of error?

Looking for the help,

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To use `wp_enqueue_script()` correctly, you need to launch your function with the action [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

In your __construct() or init function

```
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'admin_script'));
```

You can enqueue both, scripts and styles, in this function.